# Webrtc Android camera capture

Tags: android, mobile, camera, webrtc, capture

## What

Render the camera feed

see also Google discussion at:

`https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/discuss-webrtc/capturer$20android$20preview%7Csort:date/discuss-webrtc/sUIR23FftSU/5YIp7cO1BgAJ`

## Use Case

If I am on a 2G network I should see my own video in high quality while the other callee should see me pixelated.

## What does Apprtc Demo do?

Apprtc Demo renders the mediaStream videoTrack that is going to be sent on the peerConnection instead of the real Camera feed.

## What am I doing?

as Apprtc Demo

## Insights

There are two methods which were promising but didn't help

- VideoSource.adaptOutputFormat(width, height, fps)
- CameraVideoCapturer.startCapture(width, height, fps)

**as I am rendering from the peerConnection and not from the Camera.**

## Question

Do you have any idea on how I can achieve the rendering of my own camera?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a video source you attach the video capturer to it.

eg. `localVideoSource = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoSource(videoCapturer);`

So you have to implement interface `org.webrtc.VideoCapturer` then set it to the video source.

From your discussion I understand that you need better quality, you can avoid custom implementation by set your own resolution when you start the default camera as follows:

`capturer.startCapture(widthRecording, heightRecording, fpsRecording);`